# Download FX Rate from iTunesConnect / App Store Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

I distribute a number of apps on the iOS App Store, co-authored by different people. I need to pay one person for App X, another person for App Y, another person for App Z, etc.

App Store Connect offers some APIs to download sales reports, but the sales reports report earnings in foreign currencies, which Apple converts to my currency (USD) later, when Apple pays me. On the "Payments" tab in the "Payments and Financial Reports" section, the currency exchange rate is reported under the column "FX Rate."

Is there a way for me to download that table (I specifically need the FX Rate) using Apple's AutoIngest tool or another Apple API?

(Without the exact currency exchange rate on pay day, I can't divide up Apple's USD payments to me into fair allocations to each app. The sales reports only say that App X earned a certain number of USD and a certain number of EUR and a certain number of GBP, but I don't have enough information to decide exactly how much of my USD I should pay to the author of App X without knowing Apple's exact exchange rate for EUR/GBP/etc. on pay day.)

Comment: I know I could screen scrape it or copy and paste it, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Comment: Dan, did you find a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this issue myself. You can calculate the exact currency exchange rates used for any pay day by doing the following:

1. On iTunes Connect website, go to Payments & Financial Reports.
2. Select the pay period you wish to calculate exchange rates for.
3. Click the [image: financial_report.csv] download button (above Estimated Proceeds column).
4. Open the financial_report.csv file that was just generated in Numbers or Excel.
5. On each row, divide the 'Proceeds' column by the 'Total Owed' column.

Now you have the exchange rate used for each currency on that pay day. I wish this info was just supplied with the generated reports, but until it is this is a fairly easy workaround. Just do this once, then save a template and paste in new data from each pay period.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about programming to get the information, not getting it using a manual approach.

Comment: Oddly enough, a week later and I now see Apple includes the exchange rates used right in financial_report.csv file, so no need to perform any calculations anymore!

Comment: ...and the exchange rate column is gone again... so very frustrating!

Comment: Looks like the fx rate is back again (note that it appears only for financial periods for which you have been paid). Anyone know how to download the financial_report.csv file programatically? It's easy to get the link, but I can't figure out how to do authentication.

Comment: FX rates provided by Apple are not correct (not precise).